# Python JSON formatter

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am new to python. Just starting to experiment it with small programs. I saw this question where :

Input will be of json can be of this format :

```
'[ ["a","b","c"], [1,2,null], [null,3,4], [5,null,6] ]'
```

or :

```
'[ { "a":1, "b":2 }, { "b":3, "c":4 }, { "c":6, "a":5 } ]'
```

We should convert it into :

```
output = '{ "a": [1,null,5], "b": [2,3,null], "c": [null,4,6] }'
```

So far I can think of is checking each element and appending to the result. Is there any easy or better way to do this in python. Please enlighten me.

Comment: You mean `None` instead of `null` right?

Comment: @IronFist seems like `null` is valid in json. If you call `json.loads` on that string it converts it to `None`. Presumably it also works the other way round.

Comment: @PaulRooney sure it does: `json.dumps(None) == 'null'`

Comment: @PaulRooney .. correct .. :) ..thought it was in the dictionary not in the json output...didn't pay attention to that

Comment: There are two tasks involved here: Firstly, read the JSON. Secondly, change the structure of the resulting data to resemble the desired output. Which task is giving you problems?

Comment: For first one if `jj1` is json object `o1 = json.dumps({a: list(b) for a, b in zip(jj1[0], zip(*jj1[1:]))})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with `Python 3`:

```
def get_elements(json_txt):
import json
arr = json.loads(json_txt)
new = {}
list_of_keys = []
list_of_keys_from_dicts = [list(elem.keys()) for elem in arr]
# getting keys from json
for keys in list_of_keys_from_dicts:
    for key in keys:
        if key not in list_of_keys:
            list_of_keys.append(key)
for key in list_of_keys:
    new[key] = []
for element in arr:
    for key in list_of_keys:
        if key in element:
            new[key].append(element[key])
        else:
            new[key].append(None)
return json.dumps(new)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) from `collections module`, this way:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = '[ { "a":1, "b":2 }, { "b":3, "c":4 }, { "c":6, "a":5 } ]'
>>> 
>>> dic = json.loads(s)
>>> dic
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 3, 'c': 4}, {'a': 5, 'c': 6}]
>>> kys = set(k for sub_d in d for k in sub_d) #creates uniques keys of dictionary d
>>> kys
{'a', 'b', 'c'}
>>>
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> my_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for d in dic:
        for k in kys:
            my_dict[k].append(d.get(k, None))
>>> my_dict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [1, None, 5], 'b': [2, 3, None], 'c': [None, 4, 6]})
```

As for the other situation:

```
>>> s = '[ ["a","b","c"], [1,2,null], [null,3,4], [5,null,6] ]'
>>> d = json.loads(s)
>>> d
[['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, None], [None, 3, 4], [5, None, 6]]
>>> my_dict = dict(zip(d[0], zip(*d[1:])))
>>> my_dict
{'a': (1, None, 5), 'b': (2, 3, None), 'c': (None, 4, 6)}
```

If you don't want tuples as values, then:

```
>>> my_dict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in zip(d[0], zip(*d[1:])):
        my_dict[k].extend(v)
```

Finally, to group both cases into one function:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

def parse_data(data):
    data = json.loads(data) 
    my_dict = defaultdict(list)
    if isinstance(data[0], list):
        for k,v in zip(data[0], zip(*data[1:])):
            my_dict[k].extend(v)
    elif isinstance(data[0], dict):
        kys = set(k for sub_d in data for k in sub_d)
        for d in data:
            for k in kys:
                my_dict[k].append(d.get(k, None))
    return my_dict

s1 = '[ ["a","b","c"], [1,2,null], [null,3,4], [5,null,6] ]' 
d1 = parse_data(s1)
s2 = '[ { "a":1, "b":2 }, { "b":3, "c":4 }, { "c":6, "a":5 } ]'
d2 = parse_data(s2)
```

Comment: Can you explain this line : set(k for sub_d in d for k in sub_d) What is sub_d here ?

Comment: `set` will return unique element from any collections or list and because `d` is list of dictionaries, I had to use `set comprehension` for that, as if to say:
for every `sub_d` (every dictionary in list) then for every `k` in that `sub_d` ...

Comment: @Sarah .. Check my edit as I've grouped both situations into one function.

Answer (score 1):

It will works for both formates

```
import json


def convert_format(json_data):
    convert_to_py_obj = json.loads(json_data)
    new_format = dict()
    if isinstance(convert_to_py_obj, list) and len(convert_to_py_obj) > 1:
        index_0_keys = convert_to_py_obj[0]
        if isinstance(index_0_keys, list):
            for i, key in enumerate(index_0_keys):
                new_format[key] = []
                for sub_list in convert_to_py_obj[1:]:
                    new_format[key].append(sub_list[i])
        elif isinstance(index_0_keys, dict):
            for sub_dict in convert_to_py_obj:
                for key, val in sub_dict.iteritems():
                    if key in new_format:
                        new_format[key].append(val)
                    else:
                        new_format[key] = [val]
                none_keys = set(new_format.keys()) - set(sub_dict.keys())
                for key in none_keys:
                    new_format[key].append(None)
    return json.dumps(new_format)
```